# Hide second element with same class or id

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have double code in WP:

```
<div class="row top-banner">
    <div class="columns">
        <section id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">           <div class="textwidget"><img id="bannerFront" class="showRtb"  style="cursor:pointer;" src="https://www.asdasd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/treat_someone-1.png" alt="treat_someone"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried everything from WP backend and decided to use css + JavaScript to solve this. I want to only show the first top-banner. Here is the code to hide it:

```
.textwidget:nth-of-type(1) {
    display:none;
}
```

When I put that code onto my WP page, both banners disappear not just second.

How can I only hide the second banner and not the first?

Comment: I can only see one banner image in this HTML code

Comment: yes but I have this code 2 times in home page ...

Comment: it's because your `.textwidget` div is the first of it's type in the `.widget` div.  If you want a css solution, we need to see where your second banner is in relation to your first, otherwise I would use a js solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-of-type` works on siblings, in other words, they need to be children of the same parent. If they are in different parents in the page, `nth-` won't work. You could select all elements with class `.textwidget` and hide the second one (index 1) with jQuery.

```
 $('.textwidget:eq(1)').hide();
```

**Edit: ...or you could use Vanilla Javascript**

```js
// on page ready method definition
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

// run the function inside this method when page finished loading
ready(function(){
  // hide second element
  document.getElementsByClassName('textwidget')[1].style.display = 'none';
})
```

```html
<div class="row top-banner">
    <div class="columns">
      <section id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">
        <div class="textwidget">
          <img id="bannerFront" class="showRtb" style="cursor:pointer;"
               src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300"
               alt="treat_someone"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row top-banner">
    <div class="columns">
      <section id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">
        <div class="textwidget">
          <img id="bannerFront" class="showRtb" style="cursor:pointer;"
               src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300"
               alt="treat_someone"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I cant use jquery... how that will looks like with javascript ? becouse I get error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:2

Comment: tanks very much! thats it

Answer (score 1):

In Plain javascript, try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('textwidget')[1].style.display='none';
```

Comment: this is good, just fix the typo `document.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong CSS. I have modified your CSS code, it will work for you.

```
.top-banner:nth-of-type(1) {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**nth-of-type : selector matches every element that is the nth child, of a particular type, of its parent**. Here us the code which is hiding 2nd element of .textwidget

```css
.textwidget:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row top-banner">
  <div class="columns">
    <section id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">
      <div class="textwidget">1st<img id="bannerFront" class="showRtb" style="cursor:pointer;" src="" alt="treat_someone"></div>
      <div class="textwidget">2nd<img id="bannerFront" class="showRtb" style="cursor:pointer;" src="" alt="treat_someone"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```